# "set var=" works differently on XP and Windows 7

Tags: batch-file

Following code returns different ERRORLEVEL on Win XP and Win 7:

```
set "QQQ="
echo ERRORLEVEL=%ERRORLEVEL%
```

XP

```
>ERRORLEVEL=1
```

Windows 7

```
>ERRORLEVEL=0
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

XP seems to make more sense here, as it sets the errorlevel to 1, but only if QQQ is an undefined variable before.

WIN7 have two different ways!
`set` does not change the errorlevel, if the code is inside a `.BAT` file
`set` set the errorlevel always to 0, if the code is inside a `.CMD` file

Why?
Nobody knows. You can ask Microsoft, but I suppose it's simply an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: On my Win7 set command does not change ERRORLEVEL to 1 either from cmd or from bat file.

Comment: @Vladimir Bezugliy As I said, on Win7, either the errorlevel isn't changed at all (in batch-files) or it's always set to 0 (in cmd files), but Win7 never set it to 1

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP this won't work, 
since the SET command itself will set an errorlevel (usually 1)!
because the value of QQQ is not defined
but in windows 7 what happens is that SET value sets QQQ with null and thus the 
ERRORLEVEL=0
for example IN WINDOWS 7

```
set "QQQ"
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
pause
```

Environment variable QQQ not defined //ERRORLEVEL=1
and
for example IN WINDOWS 7

```
set "QQQ="   :: sets QQQ as null
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
pause
```

Environment variable QQQ not defined //ERRORLEVEL=0

Comment: sorry don't know why :) they made as ; unassigned values are set to null values

Comment: @cc4re I can't see any difference between a null value and an undefined variable

Comment: undefined means a variable has been declared but has not been assigned a value  null is an assignment value. in memory it will be pointing to some empty string ...